# How to make WampServer 3.1.0 accessible to the web

Tags: apache, wampserver

I read about changing Listening Port to 80 which is in my Server Configuration it indicates Port defined for Apache 80,I already activate WampServer to Put Online, remove the firewall, what would be the best thing to configure in the server to make it accessible online.

My Virtual Hosts

```
# Virtual Hosts # 
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName localhost 
    ServerAlias localhost 
    DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/www" 
    <Directory "C:/Wamp/www/"> 
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require local 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking port 80.  Move to a non-standard port - 4488 or something  (not the non-standard but common 8080 and 8888) - and forward that port from your firewall to the IP of the machine that is on your LAN.  Then go to `http://your.public.ip.address:4488` and you should see it

Comment: When I try to replace my listening port to 8080 in my Wamp Server Configuration it says "Not a Listen port
Error(s) See below" and the error Port used for the VirtualHost is not an Apache 'Listen port' in httpd.conf

Comment: Please say which version of WAMPServer you are using

Comment: Please show your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file in your question

Comment: I'm using the WAMPServer 3.1.0. okey I'll post it tomorrow since I'm already home and the server are at the office and also I've been following the tutor on this website but it seems no luck at all. https://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/

Comment: # Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/www"
  <Directory "C:/Wamp/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

@RiggsFolly sorry don't know how to post the codes.

Comment: Change `Require local` to `Require all granted` and the universe will be able to hack on your computer. I say that because I dont think you know enough about what you are doing do do this safely. You will be opening up an attack vector that people love to try and exploit

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thanks for the advice but even though I change the Require local with Require all granted it's still not accessible.

Comment: Have you Port Forwarded your router?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes already port forward in my router, I'll just post the capture screen so you could see it if I'm doing it right thing, and by the way we just wanna use this server for our survey using a mobile device with redcap running on it both server and mobile device  and sending the data to this server.